# How to iterate over a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I need to iterate over a vector strictly in the order the elements were pushed back into it. For my particular case it's better use iterators than iterating though the for-each loop as follows:

```
std::vector<int> vector;
for(int i = 0; i < vector.size(); i++)
   //not good, but works
```

My question is if it's realiably to iterate over the vector through iterator like that:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(typename std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.iterator(); i != v.end(); i++)
   //good, but I'm not strictly sure about the iterating order.
```

So, can I use iterators safely with my requirements? Is it standartized?

Comment: Use [range-based for loops](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: @Pradhan But I need to use iterators.

Comment: Why? The range-based for loop uses iterators under the hood.

Comment: @St.Antario This begs for a "why?". Can you elaborate?

Comment: @St.Antario To do what? If it's an important aspect of the question, it belongs *in the question*

Comment: @St.Antario what is the goal of your iteration? There are many standard algorithms you can use for common tasks, for example.

Comment: @Pradhan How can I get access to the next element? How can I check if the element is last? With iterators I can.

Comment: @Barry I need to call a function with the parameter of the type iterator recursively.

Comment: @St.Antario Put all your requirements *in the question*. Also what does recursion have to do with the question? That belongs in there too.

Comment: @St.Antario  This "How can I get access to the next element? How can I check if the element is last? With iterators I can. " is totally unclear. For example you can use incices and check whether the element is last.

Comment: @St.Antario  This question "So, can I use iterators safely with my requirements? Is it standartized?" simply does not make sense because nobody knows about your requirements.:)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you have access to C++11 you can use range-based for loops

```
for (auto i : v)
```

Otherwise you should use `begin()` and `end()`

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i)
```

You can also use `std::begin` and `std::end` (these require C++11 as well)

```
for (std::vector<int>::iterator i = std::begin(v); i != std::end(v); ++i)
```

`begin` will return an iterator to **the first element in your vector**. `end` will return an iterator to **one element past the end of your vector**. So the order in which you get the elements iterating this way is both safe and defined.

Comment: Well if you already wrote about `c++11` why not to mention a solution with `auto` instead of `std::vector<int>::iterator`?

Comment: @VictorPolevoy probably because the `std::vector<int>::iterator` solution is suggested for when you do not have C++11.

Comment: That said, non-member `begin` and `end` are C++11 as well.

Comment: @NathanOliver Regarding your edit, know that in this case the `std::` namespace on `begin` and `end` is unnecessary due to ADL since `std::vector` already belongs to the `std::` namespace. I'll leave the edit there, though, since it is more clear.

Comment: @CoryKramer I probably should have made that a comment instead of editing.  Sorry for that.

Comment: No worries, as I said I prefer your edit for clarity and explicitness

Comment: @TartanLlama So how do you know that iterator-based for loop started from the std::begin(v) and ended with std::end(v) gives us the right order? It's clear that it starts and ends with right elements, but that doesn't imply that the whole iteration will be consistent with the order.

Comment: @St.Antario Because that is how it's defined! It *must* iterate from `begin` to `end`, and *must* iterate in sequential order for ordered containers (vector, list, set, deque, map, etc)

Answer (score 4):

if you want to use iterators, your approach is fine

```
for(auto it = v.begin(); it != v.end(); ++it)
```

the iteration order depends in fact on the container and the actual used iterator.
for a std::vector this code iterates always over the elements in their order in the vector. if you'd use v.rbegin() or v.rend() instead, the order would be reversed.
for another container the order is different, for a std::set the very same code would iterate the elements in ascending order of their sorting criterion.

Answer (score 1):

This is an overly complex solution.

First, we start with an `index` type.  It can store anything that models iterator and/or integral (basically, supports + scalar, delta to scalar, copy, destruction and equality):

```
template<class T,
  class Category=std::random_access_iterator_tag,
  class Delta=decltype(std::declval<T>()-std::declval<T>())
>
struct index:
  std::iterator<Category, T, Delta, T*, T>
{
  T t;
  T operator*()const{ return t; }
  index& operator++(){++t; return *this;}
  index operator++(int){index tmp = *this; ++t; return tmp;}
  index& operator--(){--t; return *this;}
  index operator--(int){index tmp = *this; --t; return tmp;}
  T operator[](size_t i)const{return t+i;}
  friend bool operator<(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return rhs.t-lhs.t>0;
  }
  friend bool operator>(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return rhs<lhs;
  }
  friend bool operator<=(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs>rhs);
  }
  friend bool operator>=(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return !(lhs<rhs);
  }
  friend bool operator==(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t==rhs.t;
  }
  friend bool operator!=(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t!=rhs.t;
  }
  friend Delta operator-(index const& lhs, index const& rhs) {
    return lhs.t-rhs.t;
  }
  friend index& operator+=(index& lhs, Delta rhs) {
    lhs.t+=rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend index& operator-=(index& lhs, Delta rhs) {
    lhs.t-=rhs;
    return lhs;
  }
  friend index operator+(index idx, Delta scalar) {
    idx+=scalar;
    return idx;
  }
  friend index operator+(Delta scalar, index idx) {
    idx+=scalar;
    return idx;
  }
  friend index operator-(index idx, Delta scalar) {
    idx-=scalar;
    return idx;
  }
};
```

most of which isn't needed, but I wanted to be complete.  Note that this claims to be a random access iterator by default, but it lies, as its reference type is not a reference.  I consider the lie worthwhile.

With `index` we can both create an iterator-over-integrals, and an iterator-over-iterators.  Here is how we create an iterator-over-iterators:

```
using it_category=typename std::iterator_traits<It>::iterator_category;

template<class It, class Category=it_category<It>>
index<It, Category> meta_iterator( It it ) { return {it}; }
```

Next, we want to be able to take some iterators, and iterate over the range.  This means we want a range type:

```
template<class It>
struct range {
  It b, e;
  range(It s, It f):b(s),e(f){}
  range():b(),e(){}
  It begin()const{return b;}
  It end()const{return e;}
  bool empty()const{return begin()==end();}
  template<class R>
  range(R&& r):range(std::begin(r),std::end(r)){}
};
```

This is a trait that takes an iterable range (not only a `range`, but also any container) and gets the iterator type out.  Note that a superior ADL-enabled one would be a good idea:

```
template<class R>
using iterator=decltype(std::begin(std::declval<R&>()));
```

Random helpers:

```
template<class R,class It=iterator<R>>
range<It> make_range(R&&r){ return {std::forward<R>(r)}; }
template<class It
range<It> make_range(It s, It f){return {s,f};}
```

Here is a useful helper that solves our problem:

```
template<class R>
range<meta_iterator<iterator<R>> iterators_into( R&& r ){
  return {meta_iterator(std::begin(r)), meta_iterator(std::end(r))};
}
```

and we are done:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for(auto it: iterators_into(v)) {
}
```

returns an iterator for each element of `v`.

For industrial quality, you'd want to ADL-improve things.  Also, dealing with rvalue storage of input ranges lets you chain range-adaptors better in `for(:)` loops.